# How to reference a TextView in a separate layout file?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have built a navigation activity composed of 3 xml files, namely

- home_activity.xml
- nav_header.xml
- drawer_menu.xml

home_activity.xml brings these together and is set as the content view in HomeActivity.java.

Now, I'm programmatically trying to set the text of a TextView, in the nav_header.xml file but ending up with a Null Pointer Exception. I can see why, but don't quite know how to overcome this. How does one reference the original TextView and not a copy of it as is the outcome of inflating and adding it.

PS. I have 2 weeks of Android experience,

Thanks in advance

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);


  Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, 
  toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
  drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
  toggle.syncState();


  View nav_header = getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(findViewById(R.id.nav_header), null);

  TextView text_username = nav_header.findViewById(R.id.text_username);
  text_username.setText("There you go");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

View navigationHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

textUsername = navigationHeader.findViewById(R.id.text_username);

textUsername.setText("There you go");
```